# Bash: Print Command not found

Tags: bash, centos, zimbra, centos8

I am setting up Zimbra mail server on Centos 8.8.12 server OS.
while installing zimbra, I am getting following error.
**./util/utilfunc.sh: line 2314: print: command not found**
Please guide.

[image]

Comment: Please post error as text. Many users don't have access to `imgur` at workplace

Comment: ./util/utilfunc.sh: line 2314: print: command not found

Comment: https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?t=64742

Comment: used --platform-override but its failing installation at later point of time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems coming together:

1. You are not running bash, as you can see from the wording of the error message. A bash error message would start with the word *bash*, i.e. *bash: print: command not found*
2. Since *print* is not an internal command to bash (it would be one in, say, zsh), you need to have a file named `print` in one of the directories listed in your `PATH`, and this file needs to have executable permission.

Comment: @Nitesh: And the directory is in the PATH? Update your question to demonstrate how you verified this.